# Always add a certain character to an ENTRY when user types

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a simple entry where the user puts a price into via a numeric keyboard:

```
                        <Entry 
                            x:Name="entry_price"
                            TextChanged="entry_price_TextChanged"
                            TextColor="#424242"
                            MaxLength="80"
                            Keyboard="Numeric"
                            FontFamily="Font_11"
                            Grid.Column="2"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            Placeholder="0€"/>
```

Now, I want to always add the € sign to the entry string.

Say, the user enters 599, the entry shows: 599€.

I went with the TextChanged event handler :

```
    private void entry_price_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (entry_price != null)
        {
            if(!entry_price.Text.EndsWith("€"))
            {
                entry_price.Text = entry_price.Text + "€";
            }

        }
    }
```

But this led to strange results. I tried multiple approaches but ran into different issues all the time becuase changing the text inside the textchange event handler calls the function again.

Can you solve this?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/alfeugds/786260ab70a49565070338052ceaee3e

Comment: you need to use validation behavior. Do not use numeric keyboard , but use validation on  non numeric characters. When it is unfocused add pound/euro sign at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest custom a `Layout` which contains a `Label` and a `Entry` to achieve this, it will be the best solution. Because when you need to get the text of `Entry`, it will not contain "€". It will be convenient for using.

If you must need to use `Entry_TextChanged` method to achieve that, you could have a look at the following code:

```
private void entry_price_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Xamarin.Forms.Entry entry = sender as Xamarin.Forms.Entry;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.OldTextValue))
    {
        e.OldTextValue.Insert(e.OldTextValue.Length - 1, e.NewTextValue);
        entry.CursorPosition = entry.Text.Length - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        entry.Text = e.NewTextValue + "€";
    }
}
```

The effect:

[image]